# How do i run regression with my dummy variable in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have created a simple dummy in R,

```
dummy <- as.numeric(GDP >=0)
```

I want to run the regression Yi= a1 + a2Di + B1Xi + B2DiXI +ui
how do i go about this? 
ive tried

```
reg1<- lm(unempl~dummy)
```

But gave me weird results, also not sure if i ran dummy=1 or 0
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice this was exactly what i was looking for, although i'm trying to figure out how to obtain output for the relevant t stats, p values and such. Any advice?